# Find out how many times each number appears in a database using r

Tags: r, database

So I have a database which has an id and several fields such as:

```
ID   Name1   Name2   Name3
1      2       3       6
1      1       2       7
1      3       4       7
1      2       1       3
2      5       2       1
2      8       3       7
2      6       2       3
5      2       1       4
5      5       8       6
5      3       2       4
```

I would like to know what is the best way to get an overall count on how many times each number appears in the database regardless of column. and how many times does each number appear within a unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the function `gather` from the tidyr package to change the data frame to long format and then using function `ddply` from the plyr package to summarize based on ID and Value:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2,3), rep(5,3)),
             Name1 = c(2,1,3,2,5,8,6,2,5,3),
             Name2 = c(3,2,4,1,2,3,2,1,8,2),
             Name3 = c(6,7,7,3,1,7,3,4,6,4))

library(tidyr)
library(plyr)
df<-gather(df, key="ID")
ddply(df, .(value), summarize, count=length(value)) #overall count
ddply(df, .(ID,value), summarize, count=length(value)) #count by ID
```